# Position of image buttons changes while running

Tags: android, android-layout

This is my XML file to place 5 buttons on the screen. When I was placing buttons on Android studio, it looked good, but when I debugged it on a small screen size phone, the positioning of the elements were not correct, the image buttons were overlapping each other

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_01"
    android:layout_marginLeft="65dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtReceive" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_02"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtReceive"/>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_03"
    android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtReceive" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_04"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="135dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtReceive" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
    android:src="@drawable/send_btn"
    android:layout_marginLeft="165dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtReceive" />
```

Comment: Please show me what type of layout do you use?

Comment: It is relative layout.

Comment: Instead of giving margintop to all imageButton try changing the layout_below to be their top imagebutton, as the top margin value may give different result on different screen resolutions.

Comment: I apologise, and yes its a relative layout. OK i will try to change layout_below to the top imageButton

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Nikunj Sakhrelia, the ImageButtons may render differently on different screensizes and you get into trouble when setting margins to position the buttons. You better use a LinearLayout with its orientation set to vertical to ensure the imagebuttons are displayed below each other, using the margins only to create whitespace.

Comment: The problem is that  i need each button to lie just beside each other in a certain position for them to form a circle. Each button is in the shape of part of a circle

Comment: Mm.. I would try to make some sort of grid structure for that, so you can place each button in a fixed place. Have a look at gridlayout.

Comment: i have a doubt with gridlayout. Imagine a crescent shape. 4 buttons make up the crescent shape, dividing it horizontally into 4 equal parts. Now in the concave area of the crescent, a circular button will join up, forming like two circles overlapping each other. Thus 5 buttons in total, is this achievable in grid layout

Comment: no it didnt work. when i inserted the button, the grid space expanded, and i could not place other buttons nearby